# Save and Commit current file into svn repository in vim,silently

Tags: svn, vim

I'm using vim in Windows with mswin.vim included. 
It has mapped `<C-S>` to save current file:

```
" Use CTRL-S for saving, also in Insert mode
noremap <C-S>       :update<CR>
vnoremap <C-S>      <C-C>:update<CR>
inoremap <C-S>      <C-O>:update<CR>
```

I want `<C-S>` to do more:  committing current file into SVN repository after it's being saved, without pop up the CMD window. 
How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving and commiting *only that file* into a repo can be done. A small *something* will however have to pop up for you to write your commit message.

But really, I don't have to tell that that workstyle is generally bad. Commiting is not a replacement for saving, nor vice versa. Vim has some wonderful plugins for handling ll of the three major vcs players (cvs, git, hg) ... maybe it would be best if you tried one of them out first.

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to save and commit as one action. These are different things and should be.

Comment: @mliebelt - Well, go tell him that ;)

Comment: @mliebet -- may be he wants use <C-S> *for commits only* to be sure the file saved before commit and use :s and :update for usual save operations